# How to do row-level TZ to UTC conversion with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

First off, this is **not** a duplicate question of converting ***UTC to TZ***. That's not the answer I'm looking for. I'm also not looking for answers about time ***offsets***.

- TZ to UTC
- **NOT** UTC to TZ
- **NOT** offsets

## Use Case: International "Cron Jobs"

There's a batch of jobs that run according to a user-specified schedule, which should respect Daylight Savings, Summer Time, Winter Time, etc.

Essentially I have a table like this:

```
 name |      timezone       | usertime
------+---------------------+----------
 Joe  | America/New_York    | 02:00:00
 Jane | America/Chicago     | 02:00:00
 John | America/Denver      | 02:00:00
 Jess | America/Phoenix     | 02:00:00
 Jack | America/Los_Angeles | 02:00:00
 Ping | Asia/Shanghai       | 02:00:00
```

And I the question I want to ask is:

> If I count from whatever UTC day `now()` is, what time was (or will be) `usertime` in UTC?

### 0. `WITH TIME ZONE` => WRONG!

The `time` type is... worthless. The postgres documentation even warns about this, blaming the SQL standard, but it's implemented for completeness.

`timestamp` is better, but...

- `WITHOUT TIME ZONE` actually *does* apply the local system tz
- `WITH TIME ZONE` requires a time zone, but only saves the offset

It seems like it's best just to use text types.

### 1. `AT TIME ZONE` => WRONG!

This conversion is completely backwards. First of all, it displays everything relative to local system time, regardless of the timezone set. It also counting backwards (to local time) rather than forwards (to the set timezone).

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  timezone,
  usertime,
  usertime::time AT TIME ZONE timezone AS time
FROM demo;
```

```
 name |      timezone       | usertime |    time
------+---------------------+----------+-------------
 Joe  | America/New_York    | 02:00:00 | 04:00:00-04
 Jane | America/Chicago     | 02:00:00 | 03:00:00-05
 John | America/Denver      | 02:00:00 | 02:00:00-06
 Jess | America/Phoenix     | 02:00:00 | 01:00:00-07
 Jack | America/Los_Angeles | 02:00:00 | 01:00:00-07
 Ping | Asia/Shanghai       | 02:00:00 | 16:00:00+08
(5 rows)
```

### 2. Time + Timezone => WRONG!

As you can see here, the `time` type doesn't actually allow for timezones at all, just time *offsets*:

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  timezone,
  (usertime || ' ' || timezone)::time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
    AS realtime
FROM demo;
```

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "02:00:00 America/New_York"
```

### 3. timestamp + timezone => WRONG!

You'd think if you explicitly constructed the string with the timezone, such as `1985-10-26 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles`, that you'd get the correct time. Nope. It completely ignores it.

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  timezone,
  (current_date || ' ' || usertime || ' ' || timezone)::timestamp,
  usertime
FROM demo;
```

```
 name |      timezone       |      timestamp      | usertime
------+---------------------+---------------------+----------
 Joe  | America/New_York    | 2019-06-17 02:00:00 | 02:00:00
 Jane | America/Chicago     | 2019-06-17 02:00:00 | 02:00:00
 John | America/Denver      | 2019-06-17 02:00:00 | 02:00:00
 Jess | America/Phoenix     | 2019-06-17 02:00:00 | 02:00:00
 Jack | America/Los_Angeles | 2019-06-17 02:00:00 | 02:00:00
 Ping | Asia/Shanghai       | 2019-06-17 02:00:00 | 02:00:00
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Specify *exactly* the data type of your column(s). Your Question is unclear. I suspect you misunderstand the nature of the data types, and are confused about the unfortunate behavior of some tools to dynamically apply a default time zone thereby misrepresenting the contents of the database.

Comment: It seems that using `text` is the only way to go. Neither `time` nor `timestamp` actually save `timezone` information (just _offsets_) and even `WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, they apply the default time zone, as you say.

Take a look at the paired solution.

Comment: Timestamp doesn't store offsets, it just ignores offsets when saving the data.  Timestamptz uses the offsets to store the data in utc time.  Do not confuse what is stored with what is displayed, which depends on the time zone of your session.

Comment: Yes, what's mostly wrong is the clarity of your question. In your question you ask to convert the time to an UTC timestamp (and how do you "count from a day"?), and in your answer you say that you want to search for a condition efficiently. Please make your goal unambiguously clear in your question. I assume that once you can come up with a clear problem statement, the wrongness will go away pretty easily.

Comment: There's nothing mutually exclusive about wanting A) an answer and B) an efficient answer. These things are not mutually exclusive. I _think_ my proposed solution works, but it's proving difficult to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ugly Solution: Double Cast

This is an **inefficient, full table scan**, but I *think* it works correctly.

You have to

1. cast current timestamp to the target time zone
2. add that to target time (*must* be in a sub expression)
3. cast the full result into the target timezone
4. then cast *again*, to UTC

This is **extremely delicate**. The slightest modification (date/timestamp, parenthesis, ordering), will likely result in something that doesn't work.

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  timezone,
  usertime,
  ((current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE timezone)::date + usertime)
    AT TIME ZONE timezone
    AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
    AS realtime
FROM demo;
```

```
 name |      timezone       | usertime |      realtime
------+---------------------+----------+---------------------
 Ping | Asia/Shanghai       | 02:00:00 | 2019-06-17 18:00:00
 Joe  | America/New_York    | 02:00:00 | 2019-06-18 06:00:00
 Jane | America/Chicago     | 02:00:00 | 2019-06-18 07:00:00
 John | America/Denver      | 02:00:00 | 2019-06-18 08:00:00
 Jess | America/Phoenix     | 02:00:00 | 2019-06-17 09:00:00
 Jack | America/Los_Angeles | 02:00:00 | 2019-06-17 09:00:00
```

You must use `current_timestamp`, not `current_date`, and you must cast it as the target timezone, and wrap it all in parens, or else you'll have time going backwards or sideways:

```
 Jack | America/Los_Angeles | 02:00:00 | 2019-06-17 09:00:00
 Ping | Asia/Shanghai       | 02:00:00 | 2019-06-16 18:00:00
```

## How to fix Time Overflow

**Updated**: I'm not sure that 100% of the timezones are actually covered in the previous example. It seems that the "rolling backwards" happens no matter which way you go about it, just at different times for different zones.

Another approach would be to drop the date info and roll the *current* time to get the correct window for querying events:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    timezone,
    usertime,
    (((current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE timezone)::date + usertime)
      AT TIME ZONE timezone
      AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::time
      AS utc_time,
    (((current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE timezone)::date + usertime)
      AT TIME ZONE timezone
      AT TIME ZONE 'Indian/Chagos')::time
      AS ctu_time
  FROM demo
  ) as d
WHERE utc_time
  BETWEEN (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::time
    AND (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::time + INTERVAL '15 MINUTES'
  OR ctu_time
  BETWEEN (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Indian/Chagos')::time
    AND (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Indian/Chagos')::time + INTERVAL '15 MINUTES'
;
```

The problem here is that there are no numbers between `23:58` and `00:13`, so you need to pick two timezones to work with.

## More accurate, elegant, and/or efficient solutions?

I'd love to see a solution that would always show the future date/times of an event, not past ones.

I'd also be interested to know if there's a way to query something like `WHERE realtime >= now() AND realtime < near_future` without causing a full table scan.

Comment: If you're selecting every row from your table, why wouldn't you expect a full table scan?  There's no where clause and you haven't mentioned any indexes, so any query will do a full table scan.

Comment: Update to clarify. I was assuming it would be assumed that I'd want to query based on time + timezone.